# How to know when chart data is displayed?

Tags: charts, javafx

I am adding some features to a `LineChart` in `JavaFX` and I am using mostly this methods from the chart `Axis`:

- Axis#getDisplayPosition
- Axis#getValueForDisplay

The problem is this methods only return the right values when the new data I added to the chart has been rendered. So now I have this ugly workaround:

```
 new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Axis#getDisplayPosition and Axis#getValueForDisplay usage
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 10);
```

A timer which delays the execution of the code 10mS enough at least in my PC for the new data to be rendered on the screen so I can use this methods. Is there any other way to know when the chart is rendered? I have been looking all the methods I can override from `LineChart` but I can't find one that help me to know when the chart finished the rendering.

Here is a simple code to reproduce what I am saying:

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        final LineChart lineChart = new LineChart(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
        final XYChart.Series<Integer, Integer> series = new XYChart.Series<Integer, Integer>();
        ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Integer, Integer>> seriesDataSet = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        lineChart.setAnimated(false);
        lineChart.setPrefWidth(800);
        lineChart.setPrefHeight(600);
        seriesDataSet.add(series);
        lineChart.setData(seriesDataSet);

        for (int n = 0; n < 50; ++n) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Integer, Integer>(n, new Random().nextInt(20)));
        }

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().add(lineChart);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();

        // Get a display
        System.out.println(lineChart.getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(2));
        // The value is now correct and different from the previous one
        System.out.println(lineChart.getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(2));

        // Add data to the chart
        for (int n = 51; n < 80; ++n) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Integer, Integer>(n, new Random().nextInt(20)));
        }

        // Get a display
        System.out.println(lineChart.getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(2));
        // The value is now correct and different from the previous one
        System.out.println(lineChart.getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(2));

        pane.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                System.out.println(lineChart.getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(2));
            }
        });
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

the first two numbers printed are the same, then I add some data, the numbers are still the same which is wrong, they should be different from the previous ones because I added data. Now click somewhere in the chart and you'll read the right number because the chart is already rendered.

Comment: Did you try [turning off animation on the chart](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/Chart.html#setAnimated-boolean-)?

Comment: Yes, my chart is not animated!

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a [minimal, complete verifiable example (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: What if you [applyCss](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#applyCss--) and [layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#layout--) the chart after adding data and before invoking your methods which require a layout to have been performed to return the correct value (like [getDisplayPosition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/Axis.html#getDisplayPosition-T-))?

Comment: @jewelsea it worked perfectly using `applyCss()` and `layout()`! Thank you! Put it as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to this is threefold on the chart:

1. Turn off [`animation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/Chart.html#setAnimated-boolean-) before modifying data.
2. [`applyCSS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#applyCss--).
3. Request [`layout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#layout--).

Then the JavaFX system shall have been forced to calculate all of the locations of the chart components.  After, you can query the components to determine their current layout positions and boundaries.

A way to ensure an actual render occurs is to place the chart in a temporary scene and [snapshot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) it.  However, unless you actually need the rendered image for some other purpose, the `applyCSS`/`layout` combination is usually all you need for location calculation purposes.

Comment: Thank you! BTW this is only available in JavaFX 8.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in java 8 if I just move the stage.show up a bit.  Updated to add more data.

```
// Add data to the chart
    for (int n = 0; n < 50; ++n) {
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Integer, Integer>(n, new Random().nextInt(20)));
    }

    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.getChildren().add(lineChart);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 800, 600));
    primaryStage.show();

    // Get a display
    System.out.println(lineChart.getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(2));
    // The value is now correct and different from the previous one
    System.out.println(lineChart.getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(2));

    // Add data to the chart
    for (int n = 51; n < 80; ++n) {
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Integer, Integer>(n, new Random().nextInt(20)));
    }

    // Get a display
    System.out.println(lineChart.getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(5));
    // The value is now correct and different from the previous one
    System.out.println(lineChart.getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(5));
```

sout shows 30, 30 instead of 0 30 when running it the way you had it.
Now it show 30,30, 74,74 after adding more data.

I just removed the tasks and runlater.  I think that is messing up the GUI thread.  Since adding to charts has to be done on the GUI thread, I'm guessing it will wait until returning and asking for the position.

BTW, if I turn on animation, I still get the right amount.  Interestingly, the amounts print correctly before the animation is even finished.

Comment: I think this happens only when you add the data and the, you show the stage. Try this code: http://pastebin.com/24yrmA2E. I just add some more data after I get both numbers. And as you can see the new two numbers are different from each other.

Comment: Sorry but you are wrong, you are using the method right after adding data but not testing it after some time, see this code: http://pastebin.com/H191qyWN the first two numbers are the same, then I add some data, the numbers are still the same which is wrong. Now click somewhere in the chart and you'll read the right number

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  I just figured 74 was right since I got it both times.  I changed the code to ..position(4.5) and now the answer is, as always, 42.